# Software to track finances

Tags: finance, accounting

I'm setting up a small service business (2 permanent employees and 2-5 temps) aiming at computer and hardware purposes. We will have no goods input and overall only receipts for the customers.

Do you know a software which is handy to manage all the financial incomes, outcomes, loans, taxes and so on so can keep track on the financial situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your budget and what platform do you want to run on?  QuickBooks sounds like a pretty standard bit of software for this I think (though I haven't done it myself).

Comment: @EricRenouf At first, thanks! Due to trustworthiness we will have an accountant who takes care of our finances. Nevertheless I would like to have my eyes on it too (to have my own oppinion and to be not too dependent on someone else). In consequence, the budget for that is rather low. I've seen Sage costs about 20$/month or 400$/fix. I guess that's ok but, to be honest, I'm not sure about my specific needs in the end. I just want to know what's my business doing.
Thanks for the advice, will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at [GnuCash](https://www.gnucash.org/).

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform GNU/Linux, BSD, Solaris, Mac OS X and Microsoft Windows.
- Double-Entry Accounting
- Small-Business Accounting
- Reports, Graphs
- Scheduled Transactions
- Customer and Vendor tracking, Jobs, Invoicing and Bill Payment, and Tax and Billing Terms
- Using A/Receivable and A/Payable accounts you can even manage payrolls for your employees
- Different accounts can be denominated in different currencies.
- Handles internationalized dates and currencies.